# jQuery 2.1 | Trigger function after delay in textarea

Tags: timer, triggers, textarea, delay

I use this to trigger a function once a pause in typing is initiated in a textarea:

```
var keyTimer;

$("#TEXTAREA").on('keyup mouseup', function(){

if (keyTimer) {
clearTimeout(keyTimer);
}
keyTimer = setTimeout(function () {
doFunction(); // Not working, triggers only once (on focus).
}, 500);

});
```

doFunction() triggers only at first keyup pause (on focus). That function must trigger at every pause (500). Now I need to blur TEXTAREA, then focus it again to reactivate doFunction() which is useless for me. Any solution greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

Updated the code:

```
var keyTimer;

$("#TEXAREA").on('keyup mouseup', function(){

if (keyTimer) {
clearTimeout(keyTimer);
}
keyTimer = setTimeout(function () { 
doFunction(); // Formulates a string
$("#TEXAREA").trigger('change');
}, 500);

}).on('change', function(){

alert('test'); // This triggers at every keyup/mouseup delay (500)

// This section of code must work after delay (500), but it doesn't,
// it only works on Textarea blur, which is not what I want:

var txtarea = $(this);
var livecount = $("#myValue").val(); // Comes from doFunction()
if ( livecount.length > 2800 ) {
txtarea.css('color','#C00'); // Change text color of textarea
} else if ( livecount.length <= 2800 ) {
txtarea.css('color','#000'); // Change text color of textarea
}

});
```

Comment: You need a comma between your events in your event listener. 'Keyup, mouseup'.  Is your function waiting the half second before it executes?

Comment: @tlindell No need for commas between events using this bind method. The code is made to trigger a doFunction() at 500ms. The prob seems to be that a textarea change is not initiated every 500ms. I trigger a change on textarea and still nothing. An alert triggers within the function but so far a textarea change is not initiated ;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE - FINAL**

Ok, got it working finally:

```
var keyTimer;

$("#TEXTAREA").on('keyup mouseup', function(){

$(this).change(); // Need this to update keyboard character input

}).on('change', function(){

if (keyTimer) {
clearTimeout(keyTimer);
}

keyTimer = setTimeout(function () {

doFunction(); // Formulates a string

}, 200); // Delay before doFunction() so it won't slow down keyboard input

var livecount = $("#myValue"); // String value from doFunction()
if ( livecount.val().length > 2800 ) {
$(this).css('color','red'); // Change textarea text color to red for overlimit
} else if ( livecount.val().length <= 2800 ) {
$(this).css('color','black'); // Change textarea text color to black for within limit
}

});
```

It was a long day ;-)

Comment: TIP - Don't delay function execution if it doesn't disrupt keyboard input. Only try with minimum delay if absolutely neeed be.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the only think in your code that is missing is the selector that you are using in the doFunction. You are using #myValue but are actually looking for the value inside of the #TEXTAREA. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6zw4jdu/1/)

```
function doFunction(){
    console.log('not a test')
}

var keyTimer;

$("#TEXAREA").on('keyup mouseup', function(){

    if (keyTimer) {
        clearTimeout(keyTimer);
    }

    keyTimer = setTimeout(function () { 
        doFunction(); // Formulates a string
        $("#TEXAREA").trigger('change');
    }, 1000);

    }).on('change', function(){

    console.log('test'); // This triggers at every keyup/mouseup delay (500)

    // This section of code must work after delay (500), but it doesn't,
    // it only works on Textarea blur, which is not what I want:

    var txtarea = $(this);
    var livecount = $("#TEXAREA").val(); // Comes from doFunction()
    if ( livecount.length > 2800 ) {
        txtarea.css('color','#C00'); // Change text color of textarea
    } else if ( livecount.length <= 2800 ) {
        txtarea.css('color','#f00'); // Change text color of textarea
    }

});
```

Comment: @ tlindell - I wish it was that simple, but $("#myValue").val() contains the string of all joined hidden values that I need to compare with, not just from $("#TEXAREA").val(). Thx for kind input.